# Можно ли каким-то образом отследить факт шеринга в соц сети?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, facebook-api, twitter-api, sharing

При шеринге результатов через соц сеть, открывается диалоговое окно, в котором есть "поделиться". Можно ли каким-то образом отследить факт нажатия на кнопку или момент,что пользователь реально пошерил результат, а не закрыл диалогвое окно,например?